# Mostrar mensaje "no hay datos" en gráfico highchart

Tags: php, highcharts

estoy trabajando unos gráficos y salen excelentes, pero no se como mostrar un mensaje en caso que la consulta para llena el gráfico sea <=0, este es el codigo que uso:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

$(function () {
    $('#container').highcharts(
    {
        chart: {
            type: 'bar'
        },
        title: {
            text: 'Publicaciones de impacto mundial y regional'
        },
        subtitle: {
            text: 'Fuente: Instituto de investigación'
        },
        xAxis: {
            categories: ['Impacto Regional','Alto impacto'],
            title: {
                text: null
            }
        },
        yAxis: {
            min: 0,
            title: {
                text: 'Publicadas y Validadas',
                align: 'high'
            },
            labels: {
                overflow: 'justify'
            }
        },
        tooltip: {
            valueSuffix: ' Publicaciones'
        },
        plotOptions: {
            bar: {
                dataLabels: {
                    enabled: true
                }
            }
        },
        legend: {
            layout: 'vertical',
            align: 'right',
            verticalAlign: 'top',
            x: -40,
            y: 100,
            floating: true,
            borderWidth: 1,
            backgroundColor: ((Highcharts.theme && Highcharts.theme.legendBackgroundColor) || '#FFFFFF'),
            shadow: true
        },
        credits: {
            enabled: false
        },
        series: [{
            name: 'Publicaciones totales',
            data: [
            <?php
            $sql=mysql_query("SELECT DISTINCT count(tbl_docente.id_sede) as totales FROM  tbl_docente INNER JOIN  tbl_publicacion ON tbl_docente.id_docente = tbl_publicacion.id_docente WHERE tbl_docente.id_sede = 1 AND tbl_publicacion.id_estado_public = 3 AND tbl_publicacion.pub_validado = 'SI' AND pub_sjr LIKE '' OR NULL UNION SELECT DISTINCT count(tbl_docente.id_sede) as totales FROM  tbl_docente INNER JOIN tbl_publicacion ON tbl_docente.id_docente = tbl_publicacion.id_docente WHERE tbl_docente.id_sede = 1 AND tbl_publicacion.id_estado_public = 3 AND tbl_publicacion.pub_validado = 'SI' AND pub_sjr != '' OR NULL");


                    while($res=mysql_fetch_array($sql)){            
                    ?>          
                                [<?php echo $res['totales'] ?>],
                    <?php
}
?>          
            ]
        }]
    });
});
        </script>
```

Este gráfico es el que obtengo:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Pero en otra consulta, donde no hay datos que mostrar sale asi:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Entonces, en este caso quiero mostrar un mensaje que indique la no existencia de datos para graficar

Comment: De antemano muchas gracias a quienes aporten respuestas

Comment: Puedes hacer la query fuera del javascript y si tienes resultados añades el gráfico al elemento container y si no añades un html que indique que no hay resultados para ese caso.

Answer (score 0):

Lo que puedes realizar es que obtener el resultado de tu consulta con ajax, compruebas que tu consulta tenga mas de un registro y si no puedes poner que tu grafico está sin datos

```
$.ajax({
  url: 'url',
  type: 'POST',
  data: {dato:dato}
})
.done(function(res) {
  let data = JSON.parse(res);
  if(Object.keys(data).length > 0){
     //crear tu grafico normla
  }else{
    Highcharts.chart('iddiv', {
      title: {
        text: 'SIN DATOS'
      },
    });
  }
});
```